Setting correct flycheck checker with Python's poetry in Doom Emacs
I have a Python project managed with Poetry. Poetry creates virtual environments in ~/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/ where all the dependencies are installed, including pylint. This means that if I want use pylint with Flycheck, I have to set pylint's configuration file to that virtual environment. In Emacs, I can use this .dir-local.el file to set it up for each Python source file in the project:
((python-mode . ((eval . (setq-local flycheck-python-pylint-executable
                                     (replace-regexp-in-string
                                      "\n$" ""
                                      (shell-command-to-string
                                       "poetry run which pylint")))))))

But is there a way to write this in the Doom Emacs's configuration? Instead of having to copy and paste this local configuration for each Python project.

Assumming I fully understand your question - you expect to have a pylint
configuration file inside virtualenvs folder - while this can be done, however
it is not a good practice/idea - think your .py files are not placed
into a virtualenvs folder, still the poetry works. See
this pylint documentation page,
there are 12 places where a pylint configuration can be placed, and that
is searched from sub-folders up hierarchy until a configuration is found.
Of coarse, such config must be copied from project to project, but no emacs
code involved.
Note the following:

the expression (setq-local flycheck-python-pylint-executable "pylint")
is part of doomemacs python configuration file, so no need to another configuration.

ATM your doomemacs configuration is not revealed here - I mean checker syntax -
what you used - if you added +flymake then it must be removed so the
python mode to reckognize the need for flycheck.

if you use lsp, additonal settings may be needed, and some lsp server
must be installed (i.e. pyls, which can use pylint and some command line arguments).

do not use .dir-locals file(s), no needed.

you can use your home folder for pylintrc (location 11 in the provided link), but
that will be a convenient only for you - if you distribute a package to others,
place a pylint configuration in project root, despite copying.


Edit1
First verify your installation: with an open .py file of your project, try
M-x flycheck-verify-checker RET python-pylint RET and see the info
provided - if it is found or not. If not found, then edit your .bashrc/.zshrc file
and add the virtualenvs (where pandas can be found) to your path and restart bash/zsh.
The Emacs uses two kind of paths, load-path and executable-path; doom
has the command (from terminal) doom env to regenerate your envvar
file (which contains your =$PATH=, which tells Emacs where to find programs on your system.
(see faq.org file in your doomemacs/docs installation folder).
Restart doom and verify again the above variable.

Thank you for responding but I still don't know how to solve the issue. I've done two things:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59882884/vscode-doesnt-show-poetry-virtualenvs-in-select-interpreter-option
I've set the path of virtual environments to .venv
I've set the Flycheck pylint executable to .venv/bin/pylint, which surprisingly didn't work


Please specify your OS and why the first link, refers to VSCode. Also what you mean by "didn't work" - i.e. if some errors, please specify, or tell your expectation and the actual behaviour in an example.

My machine is running on Debian, and I'm referring to the first answer of that SE question: by setting poetry config virtualenvs.in-project true, I can put the virtual environment folder in the project directory, and I hoped that could tell Flycheck's pylint where the virtual environment is. The main issue is that I'm importing libraries like Pandas through Poetry's virtual environment but pylint does not include the virtual environment in its linting, so it produces an import error.

pylint may run in virtualenv, even if pandas is located there. Important is the path(s) where the packages can be found. See my edit1 in answer.

I ran flycheck-set-checker-executable and selected the project's virtual environment's pylint and it works, but I would have to run that command for all my Python buffers. And if I edit .bashrc, that would set Flycheck's pylint configuration to that specific virtual environment, for all my Python buffers, if I understand correctly.

At this stage I cannot comment further, I do not know your settings and
constraints - i.e. why do you need to place pylint in virtual environment
since pylint is a static checker/analyzer - virtual environments comes into
play when running, not editing (other analyzers: ruff, pyright). You may try also
other tools of your choice, it will be helpful to have the right tool for the right job.
